# ADSI Filter All computers from an OU using c++

Tags: c++, ldap-query, adsi

Iam new to c++. Using the help of [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676882(v=vs.85).aspx)  iam trying to fetch all the computers under a OU in domain using ADSI. But Iam getting 8254L (FILTER_UNKNOWN) error. Iam not sure what iam doing wrong here. I tried to update the filter but no change in the error. Please suggest what iam doing wrong here.

Below is the code am using for getting the list.

```
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <objbase.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <activeds.h>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


HRESULT FindComputers(IDirectorySearch *pContainerToSearch,  //  IDirectorySearch pointer to the container to search.
    LPOLESTR szFilter, //  Filter to find specific users.
    //  NULL returns all user objects.
    LPOLESTR *pszPropertiesToReturn, //  Properties to return for user objects found.
    //  NULL returns all set properties.
    BOOL bIsVerbose //  TRUE indicates that display all properties for the found objects.
    //  FALSE indicates that only the RDN.
    );


//  Entry point for the application.
void wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    //  Initialize COM.
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    //  Get rootDSE and the current user domain container distinguished name.
    IADs *pObject = NULL;
    IDirectorySearch *pContainerToSearch = NULL;
    LPOLESTR szPath = new OLECHAR[MAX_PATH];
    BOOL bReturnVerbose = FALSE;
    DWORD dwLength = MAX_PATH * 2;
    LPOLESTR pszBuffer = new OLECHAR[dwLength];
    VARIANT var;

    hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://rootDSE",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, // Use Secure Authentication.
        IID_IADs,
        (void**)&pObject);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"Cannot execute query. Cannot bind to LDAP://rootDSE.\n");
        if (pObject)
            pObject->Release();
        return;
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pObject->Get(_bstr_t("defaultNamingContext"), &var);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            wprintf(L"bstrVal: %s\n", var.bstrVal);
            //  Build path to the domain container.

          // wcsncpy_s(szPath, L"LDAP://", MAX_PATH);
          // wcsncat_s(szPath, var.bstrVal, MAX_PATH - wcslen(szPath));


           //hr = ADsOpenObject(szPath,
           hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://OU=IA Computers,OU=Infosys,DC=iaseries,Dc=local",
                NULL,
                NULL,
                ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, //  Use Secure Authentication.
                IID_IDirectorySearch,
                (void**)&pContainerToSearch);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = FindComputers(pContainerToSearch, //  IDirectorySearch pointer to domainDNS container.
                    pszBuffer,
                    NULL, //  Return all properties.
                    bReturnVerbose
                    );
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    if (S_FALSE == hr)
                        wprintf(L"Computer object cannot be found.\n");
                }
                else if (E_ADS_INVALID_FILTER == hr)
                    wprintf(L"Cannot execute query. Invalid filter was specified.\n");
                else
                    wprintf(L"Query failed to run. HRESULT: %x\n", hr);

            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"Cannot execute query. Cannot bind to the container.\n");
            }
            if (pContainerToSearch)
                pContainerToSearch->Release();

        }
        VariantClear(&var);

    }

    if (pObject)
        pObject->Release();

    //  Uninitialize COM.
    CoUninitialize();
    delete[] szPath;
    delete[] pszBuffer;

    getchar();

}


HRESULT FindComputers(IDirectorySearch *pContainerToSearch,  //  IDirectorySearch pointer to the container to search.
    LPOLESTR szFilter, //  Filter for finding specific users.
    //  NULL returns all user objects.
    LPOLESTR *pszPropertiesToReturn, //  Properties to return for user objects found.
    //  NULL returns all set properties.
    BOOL bIsVerbose    //  TRUE indicates that all properties for the found objects are displayed.
    //  FALSE indicates only the RDN.
    )
{
    if (!pContainerToSearch)
        return E_POINTER;
    DWORD dwLength = (MAX_PATH * 2)+100;
    // Create search filter.
    LPOLESTR pszSearchFilter = new OLECHAR[dwLength];

    //  Add the filter.
    //swprintf_s(pszSearchFilter, dwLength, L"((objectClass=Computer)%s)", szFilter);
    swprintf_s(pszSearchFilter, dwLength, L"(&(objectClass=*)(objectCategory=Computer)%s)", szFilter);


    //  Specify subtree search.
    ADS_SEARCHPREF_INFO SearchPrefs;
    SearchPrefs.dwSearchPref = ADS_SEARCHPREF_SEARCH_SCOPE;
    SearchPrefs.vValue.dwType = ADSTYPE_INTEGER;
    SearchPrefs.vValue.Integer = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE;
    DWORD dwNumPrefs = 1;

    //  COL for iterations.
    LPOLESTR pszColumn = NULL;
    ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN col;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    //  Interface Pointers
    IADs  *pObj = NULL;
    IADs  * pIADs = NULL;

    //  Search handle.
    ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE hSearch = NULL;

    //  Set search preference.
    hr = pContainerToSearch->SetSearchPreference(&SearchPrefs, dwNumPrefs);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    LPOLESTR pszBool = NULL;
    DWORD dwBool = 0;
    PSID pObjectSID = NULL;
    LPOLESTR szSID = NULL;
    LPOLESTR szDSGUID = new WCHAR[39];
    LPGUID pObjectGUID = NULL;
    SYSTEMTIME systemtime;
    DATE date;
    VARIANT varDate;
    LPOLESTR *pszPropertyList = NULL;
    LPOLESTR pszNonVerboseList[] = { L"name", L"distinguishedName" };

    LPOLESTR szName = new OLECHAR[MAX_PATH];
    LPOLESTR szDN = new OLECHAR[MAX_PATH];

    VariantInit(&varDate);

    int iCount = 0;
    DWORD x = 0L;



    if (!bIsVerbose)
    {
        //  Return non-verbose list properties only.
        hr = pContainerToSearch->ExecuteSearch(pszSearchFilter,
            pszNonVerboseList,
            sizeof(pszNonVerboseList) / sizeof(LPOLESTR),
            &hSearch
            );
    }
    else
    {
        if (!pszPropertiesToReturn)
        {
            //  Return all properties.
            hr = pContainerToSearch->ExecuteSearch(pszSearchFilter,
                NULL,
                (DWORD)-1,
                &hSearch
                );
        }
        else
        {
            //  Specified subset.
            pszPropertyList = pszPropertiesToReturn;
            //  Return specified properties.
            hr = pContainerToSearch->ExecuteSearch(pszSearchFilter,
                pszPropertyList,
                sizeof(pszPropertyList) / sizeof(LPOLESTR),
                &hSearch
                );
        }
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        //  Call IDirectorySearch::GetNextRow() to retrieve the next data row.
        hr = pContainerToSearch->GetFirstRow(hSearch);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            while (hr != S_ADS_NOMORE_ROWS)
            {
                //  Keep track of count.
                iCount++;
                if (bIsVerbose)
                    wprintf(L"----------------------------------\n");
                //  Loop through the array of passed column names,
                //  print the data for each column.

                while (pContainerToSearch->GetNextColumnName(hSearch, &pszColumn) != S_ADS_NOMORE_COLUMNS)
                {
                    hr = pContainerToSearch->GetColumn(hSearch, pszColumn, &col);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        //  Print the data for the column and free the column.
                        if (bIsVerbose)
                        {
                            //  Get the data for this column.
                            wprintf(L"%s\n", col.pszAttrName);
                            switch (col.dwADsType)
                            {
                            case ADSTYPE_DN_STRING:
                                for (x = 0; x< col.dwNumValues; x++)
                                {
                                    wprintf(L"  %s\r\n", col.pADsValues[x].DNString);
                                }
                                break;
                            case ADSTYPE_CASE_EXACT_STRING:
                            case ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING:
                            case ADSTYPE_PRINTABLE_STRING:
                            case ADSTYPE_NUMERIC_STRING:
                            case ADSTYPE_TYPEDNAME:
                            case ADSTYPE_FAXNUMBER:
                            case ADSTYPE_PATH:
                                for (x = 0; x< col.dwNumValues; x++)
                                {
                                    wprintf(L"  %s\r\n", col.pADsValues[x].CaseIgnoreString);
                                }
                                break;
                            case ADSTYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                for (x = 0; x< col.dwNumValues; x++)
                                {
                                    dwBool = col.pADsValues[x].Boolean;
                                    pszBool = dwBool ? L"TRUE" : L"FALSE";
                                    wprintf(L"  %s\r\n", pszBool);
                                }
                                break;
                            case ADSTYPE_INTEGER:
                                for (x = 0; x< col.dwNumValues; x++)
                                {
                                    wprintf(L"  %d\r\n", col.pADsValues[x].Integer);
                                }
                                break;
                            case ADSTYPE_OCTET_STRING:
                                if (_wcsicmp(col.pszAttrName, L"objectSID") == 0)
                                {
                                    for (x = 0; x< col.dwNumValues; x++)
                                    {
                                        pObjectSID = (PSID)(col.pADsValues[x].OctetString.lpValue);
                                        //  Convert SID to string.
                                        ConvertSidToStringSid(pObjectSID, &szSID);
                                        wprintf(L"  %s\r\n", szSID);
                                        LocalFree(szSID);
                                    }
                                }
                                else if ((_wcsicmp(col.pszAttrName, L"objectGUID") == 0))
                                {
                                    for (x = 0; x< col.dwNumValues; x++)
                                    {
                                        //  Cast to LPGUID.
                                        pObjectGUID = (LPGUID)(col.pADsValues[x].OctetString.lpValue);
                                        //  Convert GUID to string.
                                        ::StringFromGUID2(*pObjectGUID, szDSGUID, 39);
                                        //  Print the GUID.
                                        wprintf(L"  %s\r\n", szDSGUID);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                    wprintf(L"  Value of type Octet String. No Conversion.");
                                break;
                            case ADSTYPE_UTC_TIME:
                                for (x = 0; x< col.dwNumValues; x++)
                                {
                                    systemtime = col.pADsValues[x].UTCTime;
                                    if (SystemTimeToVariantTime(&systemtime,
                                        &date) != 0)
                                    {
                                        //  Pack in variant.vt.
                                        varDate.vt = VT_DATE;
                                        varDate.date = date;
                                        VariantChangeType(&varDate, &varDate, VARIANT_NOVALUEPROP, VT_BSTR);
                                        wprintf(L"  %s\r\n", varDate.bstrVal);
                                        VariantClear(&varDate);
                                    }
                                    else
                                        wprintf(L"  Could not convert UTC-Time.\n", pszColumn);
                                }
                                break;
                            case ADSTYPE_NT_SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR:
                                for (x = 0; x< col.dwNumValues; x++)
                                {
                                    wprintf(L"  Security descriptor.\n");
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                wprintf(L"Unknown type %d.\n", col.dwADsType);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
#ifdef _MBCS
                            //  Verbose handles only the two single-valued attributes: cn and ldapdisplayname,
                            //  so this is a special case.
                            if (0 == wcscmp(L"name", pszColumn))
                            {
                                //wcscpy_s(szName, col.pADsValues->CaseIgnoreString);
                                szName = col.pADsValues->CaseIgnoreString;
                            }
                            if (0 == wcscmp(L"distinguishedName", pszColumn))
                            {
                                //wcscpy_s(szDN, col.pADsValues->CaseIgnoreString);
                                szDN = col.pADsValues->CaseIgnoreString;
                            }
#endif _MBCS
                        }
                        pContainerToSearch->FreeColumn(&col);
                    }
                    FreeADsMem(pszColumn);
                }
                if (!bIsVerbose)
                    wprintf(L"%s\n  DN: %s\n\n", szName, szDN);
                //  Get the next row.
                hr = pContainerToSearch->GetNextRow(hSearch);
            }

        }
        //  Close the search handle to cleanup.
        pContainerToSearch->CloseSearchHandle(hSearch);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && 0 == iCount)
        hr = S_FALSE;

    delete[] szName;
    delete[] szDN;
    delete[] szDSGUID;
    delete[] pszSearchFilter;
    return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iam able to figure out the issue. Below is the code for working sample.
I haven't cleaned the code much. Please update if you intend to use.

```html
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <objbase.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <activeds.h>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


HRESULT FindComputers(IDirectorySearch *pContainerToSearch);  //  IDirectorySearch pointer to the container to search.
 


//  Entry point for the application.
void wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
 //  Initialize COM.
 CoInitialize(NULL);
 HRESULT hr = S_OK;
 //  Get rootDSE and the current user domain container distinguished name.
 IADs *pObject = NULL;
 IDirectorySearch *pContainerToSearch = NULL;
 LPOLESTR szPath = new OLECHAR[MAX_PATH];
 BOOL bReturnVerbose = FALSE;
 DWORD dwLength = MAX_PATH * 2;
 VARIANT var;
 
 hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://rootDSE",
  NULL,
  NULL,
  ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, // Use Secure Authentication.
  IID_IADs,
  (void**)&pObject);
 if (FAILED(hr))
 {
  wprintf(L"Cannot execute query. Cannot bind to LDAP://rootDSE.\n");
  if (pObject)
   pObject->Release();
  return;
 }
 if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
 {
  hr = pObject->Get(_bstr_t("defaultNamingContext"), &var);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
  {
   //wprintf(L"bstrVal: %s\n", var.bstrVal);
   
   //  Build path to the domain container.
     // wcsncpy_s(szPath, L"LDAP://", MAX_PATH);
    // wcsncat_s(szPath, var.bstrVal, MAX_PATH - wcslen(szPath));
   
     
     //hr = ADsOpenObject(szPath,
     hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://OU=IA Computers,OU=MyDept,DC=Test,Dc=com",
    NULL,
    NULL,
    ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, //  Use Secure Authentication.
    IID_IDirectorySearch,
    (void**)&pContainerToSearch);

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
    hr = FindComputers(pContainerToSearch); //  IDirectorySearch pointer to domainDNS container.
     
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
     if (S_FALSE == hr)
      wprintf(L"Computer object cannot be found.\n");
    }
    else if (E_ADS_INVALID_FILTER == hr)
     wprintf(L"Cannot execute query. Invalid filter was specified.\n");
    else
     wprintf(L"Query failed to run. HRESULT: %x\n", hr);

   }
   else
   {
    wprintf(L"Cannot execute query. Cannot bind to the container.\n");
   }
   if (pContainerToSearch)
    pContainerToSearch->Release();

  }
  VariantClear(&var);

 }

 if (pObject)
  pObject->Release();

 //  Uninitialize COM.
 CoUninitialize();
 delete[] szPath;

 getchar();
 
}


HRESULT FindComputers(IDirectorySearch *pContainerToSearch)  //  IDirectorySearch pointer to the container to search.
{
 if (!pContainerToSearch)
  return E_POINTER;
 DWORD dwLength = (MAX_PATH * 2);
 // Create search filter.
 LPOLESTR pszSearchFilter = new OLECHAR[dwLength];

 //  Add the filter.
 pszSearchFilter = L"((objectCategory=computer))";
 
 //  Specify subtree search.
 ADS_SEARCHPREF_INFO SearchPrefs;
 SearchPrefs.dwSearchPref = ADS_SEARCHPREF_SEARCH_SCOPE;
 SearchPrefs.vValue.dwType = ADSTYPE_INTEGER;
 SearchPrefs.vValue.Integer = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE;
 DWORD dwNumPrefs = 1;

 //  COL for iterations.
 LPOLESTR pszColumn = NULL;
 ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN col;
 HRESULT hr = S_OK;

 //  Interface Pointers
 IADs  *pObj = NULL;
 IADs  * pIADs = NULL;

 //  Search handle.
 ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE hSearch = NULL;

 //  Set search preference.
 hr = pContainerToSearch->SetSearchPreference(&SearchPrefs, dwNumPrefs);
 if (FAILED(hr))
  return hr;

 LPOLESTR pszNonVerboseList[] = { L"name", L"distinguishedName" };

 LPOLESTR szName = new OLECHAR[MAX_PATH];
 LPOLESTR szDN = new OLECHAR[MAX_PATH];
  
 int iCount = 0;
 DWORD x = 0L;
 

 //  Return non-verbose list properties only.
 hr = pContainerToSearch->ExecuteSearch(pszSearchFilter,
  pszNonVerboseList,
  sizeof(pszNonVerboseList) / sizeof(LPOLESTR),
  &hSearch
  );

 if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
 {
  //  Call IDirectorySearch::GetNextRow() to retrieve the next data row.
  hr = pContainerToSearch->GetFirstRow(hSearch);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
  {
   while (hr != S_ADS_NOMORE_ROWS)
   {
    //  Keep track of count.
    iCount++;
    
    //  Loop through the array of passed column names,
    //  print the data for each column.

    while (pContainerToSearch->GetNextColumnName(hSearch, &pszColumn) != S_ADS_NOMORE_COLUMNS)
    {
     hr = pContainerToSearch->GetColumn(hSearch, pszColumn, &col);
     if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
     {
      //  Verbose handles only the two single-valued attributes: cn and ldapdisplayname,
      //  so this is a special case.
      if (0 == wcscmp(L"name", pszColumn))
      {
       //wcscpy_s(szName, col.pADsValues->CaseIgnoreString);
       szName = col.pADsValues->CaseIgnoreString;
      }
      if (0 == wcscmp(L"distinguishedName", pszColumn))
      {
       //wcscpy_s(szDN, col.pADsValues->CaseIgnoreString);
       szDN = col.pADsValues->CaseIgnoreString;
      }
   
      pContainerToSearch->FreeColumn(&col);
     }
     FreeADsMem(pszColumn);
    }
    
    wprintf(L"%s\n  DN: %s\n\n", szName, szDN);

    //  Get the next row.
    hr = pContainerToSearch->GetNextRow(hSearch);
   }

  }
  //  Close the search handle to cleanup.
  pContainerToSearch->CloseSearchHandle(hSearch);
 }
 if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && 0 == iCount)
  hr = S_FALSE;

 delete[] szName;
 delete[] szDN;
 delete[] pszSearchFilter;
 return hr;
}
```

Thanks,
Vijay